# Bug in AbstractApplicationContext-publishEvent-method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bug-reporting

I think there is a bug in method publishEvent of class AbstractApplicationContext:

```
public void publishEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
    Assert.notNull(event, "Event must not be null");
    if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        logger.trace("Publishing event in " + getDisplayName() + ": " + event);
    }
    getApplicationEventMulticaster().multicastEvent(event);
    if (this.parent != null) {
        this.parent.publishEvent(event);
    }
}
```

In a MVC-application there is a spring-context-hierarchy, root- and child-context. If i refresh child-context, then this method would refresh parent-context too. BUT it must not do it with the same ApplicationEvent-object as it contains source property that references the context, that was refreshed:

```
/**
 * Create a new ApplicationEvent.
 * @param source the component that published the event (never {@code null})
 */
public ApplicationEvent(Object source) {
    super(source);
    this.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

So, i think it is wrong, if parent (root) context sends a event and says, that child-context was refreshed. 
There is for example class SourceFilteringListener that uses this property to decide, if an event should be delivered:

```
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == this.source) {
        onApplicationEventInternal(event);
    }
}
```

Is my assumption correct (and it is a bug) ???
The reason why i think so is that i investigate a bug in my MVC-application, and i try to find out why some component did not receive refresh-event.